# Insert statement into SQL Server db

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC Web Application using SQL Server.

I am trying to INSERT a new entry into my database and I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I get an exception on the line:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The code is:

```
try
            {
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UniversityManager;Integrated Security=True");

                using (connection)
                {
                    //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    //    "INSERT INTO Students VALUES(@Id, @Name, @Surname, @Year, @PhoneNumber, @Cnp);",
                    //    connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO Students(Id,Name,Surname,Year,PhoneNumber,Cnp) " +
                        "VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Surname, @Year, @PhoneNumber, @Cnp)";
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 5;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = collection.Name;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Surname"].Value = collection.Surname;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int);
                    command.Parameters["@Year"].Value = collection.Year;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@PhoneNumber"].Value = collection.PhoneNumber;

                    command.Parameters.Add("@Cnp", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    command.Parameters["@Cnp"].Value = collection.Cnp;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: You need to provide the inner exception in order for help on this one my friend.

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."
Time: 5/24/2014 10:46:55 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[3416]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YEAR is a reserved keyword for Sql Server. So, if you really have a column with that name, then you need to enclose it in square brackets every time you refer to it. Better change that name

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO Students(Id,Name,Surname,[Year],PhoneNumber,Cnp) " +
              "VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Surname, @Year, @PhoneNumber, @Cnp)";
```

Another possibility is the `Id` column. If this column has the `IDENTITY` property set to true, then you should not set a value for it. It is automatically calculated by the database engine.

Looking at your innerexception message, it seems the problem is due to one or more of your parameters contains more text than allowed by the database field size.
You could try something like this (for each varchar parameter)

```
 // Assuming the Name field is defined as varchar(15)
 command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
 command.Parameters["@Name"].Value = collection.Name;
```

Comment: Try to read also the message in the InnerException property of the main exception

Comment: Followed your Id suggestion yet still nothing.

Comment: Could you add some information on the schema of the table Students? (Column name, DataType, Size and nullability)

Comment: Id int null,Name varchar null,Surname varchar null,[Year int null,PhoneNumber varchar null,Cnp varchar null

Comment: I can't find any obvious error in your code. I would try to use [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Add and then set the value, just to see if the automatic type assignement makes any difference

Comment: Exception:Thrown: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown: "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."
Time: 5/24/2014 10:46:55 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[3416]

Comment: It seems that one of your parameters contains more text than allowed by the size of the database field.

Comment: Exception:Caught: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'UniversityManager.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was caught: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'UniversityManager.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."
Time: 5/24/2014 10:55:24 PM
Thread:Worker Thread[4160]

Comment: I know, but i was indeed entering a longer value and now i get this new one.

Comment: Have you restored the parameter for the ID column?

Comment: OMG, I'm too tired for my own good. Yup, that's what I did. It works now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The `String or binary data would be truncated` exception means you're trying to insert a value that is too large for one of the columns in your Student table. For example, your `Name` field has a maximum length of 10 but you're trying to insert a 15 character name.

Check the values you're inserting and see if they're too large for the columns.

Comment: i get this one now: Exception:Caught: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'UniversityManager.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) A System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was caught: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'UniversityManager.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated." Time: 5/24/2014 10:55:24 PM Thread:Worker